# git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand is not truly recursive

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have the following project structure:

```
root-project
      |
      |-- A
      |   |
      |   |-- C
      |
      |-- B
```

A and B are submodules of the root-project. C is in turn a submodule
of project A. Suppose I have made changes to projects A,B and C and
commited these changes to the respective indices. After that I update
the references to A and B in the root-project and commit that change
as well. When I push the changes of the root-project with the option
--recurse-submodules=on-demand, git pushes all commits of projects A,
B and the root-project, but silently ignores the commits of
project C. I would expect that it pushes the changes of project C as well.

I know that i can work around this problem by using the following two commands in the root-project folder.

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git push origin master'
git push
```

Could someone clarify whether I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug in git-push.I have already asked this question on the git mailing list but didn't  receive any response: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/266184

I have also written a small shell script that sets up the described project structure and executes the recursive push operation:
https://gist.github.com/usommerl/6e8defcba94bd4ba1438

git version 2.3.3

Comment: Did you `git add C` in the `A` submodule first?  Committing to a submodule is like saving changes to a file, you have to `git add` the new content.

Answer (score 3):

`git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand` will be truly recursive with git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017), but with some condition.

See [commit c7be720](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7be7201a7b71f590325f0d858f909a4c0b443f6) (20 Jul 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a49794d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a49794d10826ef7cc9237abcf6474cd826de1063), 22 Aug 2017)</sup>

submodule--helper: teach push-check to handle HEAD

> In [06bf4ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06bf4ad1db92c32af38e16d9b7f928edbd647780) (`push`: propagate remote and refspec with
>   --recurse-submodules, git 2.13.0) push was taught how to propagate a refspec down to submodules when the '`--recurse-submodules`' flag is given.
>
> The **only refspecs that are allowed to be propagated are ones which name a ref which exists in both the superproject and the submodule**, with the caveat that 'HEAD' was disallowed.
>
> This patch teaches push-check (the submodule helper which determines if
>   a refspec can be propagated to a submodule) to permit propagating '`HEAD`'
>   **if and only if**:
>
> - the superproject and the submodule both have the same
>     named branch checked out and
> - the submodule is not in a detached head state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just build a version of git which includes the commit you mentioned (git version 2.14.1.459.g238e487). Unfortunately, this patch does not seem to resolve the described issue. Every repository in my [test script](https://gist.github.com/usommerl/6e8defcba94bd4ba1438) uses the same named branch (master) and none of the submodules is in a detached head state.

Comment: @UweSommerlatt OK. That is strange, as master should only be used when updating a submodule with the --remote option (it seeks to follow a default remote branch: master, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37879715/6309)

Answer (score 0):

> Copy of my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947509/1952991)

The command `git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand` does not work if you have submodules which contain submodules. (`git` version: 2.20.1)

Add the following alias in your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    push-all = "! find . -depth -name .git -exec dirname {} \\; 2> /dev/null | sort -n -r | xargs -I{} bash -c \"cd {}; git status | grep ahead > /dev/null && { echo '* Pushing: {}'; git push; }\""
```

Then issue `git push-all` in your parent git folder.

### Explanation

- `!`: We are issuing a non-git command.
- `find . -depth -name .git -exec dirname {} \\; 2> /dev/null` : Find all submodules (and git repositories, which wouldn't harm)
- `| sort -n -r`: Sort by path depth, deepest will be first.
- `| xargs -I{} bash -c \"`: Pass directories to the following commands:

  - `cd {};`: `cd` to the target directory.
  - `git status | grep ahead > /dev/null`: Test if it is necessary to push this repository.
  - `&& { echo '* Pushing: {}'; git push; }\""`: Inform and push.