# Git: track branch in submodule but commit in other submodule (possibly nested)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

I am looking for a situation in which I have a git structure with (possibly nested submodules). For each of these submodules, I want to specify separately, whether they should track a branch
(see e.g., [Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag))

For instance, my project may look like this:

```
main.tex
|- submod1 @ master
|    |-subsubmod1 @qsdf123
|- submod2 @ master
|    |-subsubmod2 @shasha12
|- submod3 @ qsdf321
```

Now, I want a way to update my submodules.

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

will update all submodules to their last recorded sha (i.e., it will work for subsubmod1, subsubmod2 and submod3, but do wrong stuff for the rest. 
On the other hand

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

will update all submodules to the associated branch (by default, master), i.e., it will work for submod1 and submod2, but do wrong stuff for the rest.

Is there a way to get this done nicely?

In response to the first answer, I'll clarify what I mean by "do wrong stuff".

Here is a small example

```bash
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/bartb/Desktop/test/.git/
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ git submodule add ../remote/ submod1
Cloning into 'submod1'...
done.
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ git submodule add ../remote/ submod2
Cloning into 'submod2'...
done.
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ cd submod1
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test/submod1 $ git log
commit 42d476962fc4e25c64ff2a807d2bf9b3e2ea31f8
Author: Bart Bogaerts <bart.bogaerts@cs.kuleuven.be>
Date:   Tue Jun 21 08:56:05 2016 +0300

    init commit

commit db1ba3bc4b02df4677f1197dc137ff36ddfeeb5f
Author: Bart Bogaerts <bart.bogaerts@cs.kuleuven.be>
Date:   Tue Jun 21 08:55:52 2016 +0300

    init commit
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test/submod1 $ git checkout db1ba3bc4b02df4677f1197dc137ff36ddfeeb5f
Note: checking out 'db1ba3bc4b02df4677f1197dc137ff36ddfeeb5f'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at db1ba3b... init commit
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test/submod1 $ cd ..
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ git config -f .gitmodules submodule.submod2.branch master
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ git commit -a -m "modules"
[master (root-commit) ea9e55f] modules
 3 files changed, 9 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 submod1
 create mode 160000 submod2
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $  git submodule update --recursive --remote
Submodule path 'submod1': checked out '42d476962fc4e25c64ff2a807d2bf9b3e2ea31f8'
bartb@EB-Latitude-E5450 ~/Desktop/test $ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   submod1 (new commits)
```

As you can see, after the latest `git submodule update --remote` submod1 is checked out at the master, even though I never configured the master branch for it. That's what I mean by "do wrong stuff"

The same thing happens for subsubmodules: they are all checked out at master instead of at their specific commit.

This "issue" is actually the expected of `git submodule update --remote`. From the git documentation:

```
This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch. The remote used is branch’s remote (branch.<name>.remote), defaulting to origin. The remote branch used defaults to master, but the branch name may be overridden by setting the submodule.<name>.branch option in either .gitmodules or .git/config (with .git/config taking precedence).
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Especially the part:

```
The remote branch used defaults to master
```

This is what I want to avoid.

**Edit**: an additional request is: I do not want to make any modifications to submods or subsubmods (these are joint projects).

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: git version 2.6.0.rc3

Comment: Does the issue persists with 2.9.0?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that I did the above test on a different pc (should check what git version is installed there).

Comment: I currently don't have access to a PC on which I have decent rights. I'll check whether it persists tomorrow.

Comment: However, I do expect it to persist, since this is not a bug, it's a feature (I'll update my question to argue this)

Comment: What about my suggestion to put a different branch in the .git modules of those submodules? That should prevent the kind of recursive behavior that you see.

Comment: It does indeed, but it would force me to keep in my subsubmodules an extra branch up-to-date. 

This is not feasible for me. The main repository is a private one, but all submodules (and subsubmodules) are shared among a team of developers.

I cannot expect the other developers to keep a branch up-to-date in al subsubmodules that only serves to make my submodule update --remote work.

Comment: Just checked: it persists on git version 2.7.4

Comment: And on version 2.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2020:

The [OP BartBog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274140/bartbog) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879715/git-track-branch-in-submodule-but-commit-in-other-submodule-possibly-nested/37924157?noredirect=1#comment110622898_37924157):

> The current (2016) answer does not work that well (anymore?) with subsubmodules since `$top/.gitmodules` does not contain the branch info of the subsub (and subsubsub modules)

> New solution:

> ```
> export top=$(pwd) 
> git submodule foreach 'b=$(git config -f ${top}/.gitmodules submodule.${path}.branch); \
>   case "${b}" in \
>     "") git checkout ${sha1}; git su ;; 
>     *) git checkout ${b}; git pull origin ${b}; git su;; 
>   esac')
> ```
>
> where `git-su` is the name of my script

---

Original 2016 answer:

> will update all submodules to the associated branch (by default, master), i.e., it will work for submod1 and submod2, but do wrong stuff for the rest.

Actually, yes, it will do "wrong stuff for the rest".

I will illustrate that bug with an example below (a repo named `parent` with a submodule '`sub`', itself with a submodule '`subsub`'), using git version 2.9.0.windows.1.

And I will propose a simple workaround allowing `sub` to follow `master`, while making sure `subsub` is not checked out at its own `master`.

---

### Setup

Let's make a repo `subsub` with two commits:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm
> git init subsub1
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/git/tests/subm/subsub1/.git/
> cd subsub1
> git commit --allow-empty -m "subsub c1"
[master (root-commit) f3087a9] subsub c1
> git commit --allow-empty -m "subsub c2"
[master 03d08cc] subsub c2
```

Lets make that repo `subsub` a submodule of another repo '`sub`':

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm
> git init sub
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/git/tests/subm/sub/.git/

> cd sub
> git submodule add -- ../subsub
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/subm/sub/subsub'...
done.
```

By default, that submodule '`subsub`' is checked out at its own `master` HEAD ([`gl` is an alias for `git log` with pretty format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064431/6309)):

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\sub\subsub
> gl
* 03d08cc  - (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) subsub c2 (4 minutes ago) VonC
* f3087a9  - subsub c1 (4 minutes ago) VonC
```

Let's make sure `sub` has `subsub` checked out at `c1` (which is *not* `master HEAD C2`):

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\sub\subsub
> git checkout @~
Note: checking out '@~'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state.     
HEAD is now at f3087a9... subsub c1
> git br -avv
* (HEAD detached at f3087a9) f3087a9 subsub c1
  master                03d08cc [origin/master] subsub c2
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master 03d08cc subsub c2
```

Let's add and commit that submodule '`subsub`' (checked out at `master~1` `c1`) in its parent repo '`sub`':

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\sub\subsub
> cd ..
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\sub
> git add .
> git commit -m "subsub at HEAD-1"
[master (root-commit) 1b8144b] subsub at HEAD-1
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 subsub
```

Let's add a couple of commits in that repo '`sub`':

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\sub
> git commit --allow-empty -m "sub c1"
[master b7d1c40] sub c1
> git commit --allow-empty -m "sub c2"
[master c77f4b2] sub c2

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\sub
> gl
* c77f4b2  - (HEAD -> master) sub c2 (2 seconds ago) VonC
* b7d1c40  - sub c1 (3 seconds ago) VonC
* 1b8144b  - subsub at HEAD-1 (77 seconds ago) VonC
```

The latest commit of `sub` does reference its submodule '`subsub`' at the right commit (the subsub `c1` one, not the `c2` one)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\sub
> git ls-tree @
100644 blob 25a0feba7e1c1795be3b8e7869aaa5dba29d33e8    .gitmodules
160000 commit f3087a9bc9b743625e0799f57c017c82c50e35d6  subsub
              ^^^
              That is subsub master~1 commit c1
```

Finally, let's make a main parent repo '`parent`' and add '`sub`' as a submodule:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm
> git init parent
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/git/tests/subm/parent/.git/
> cd parent

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent
> git submodule add -- ../sub
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/subm/parent/sub'...
done.
```

Let's make sure that `sub` is *not* checked out at its `master` HEAD (like we did before for `subsub`)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent
> cd sub

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent\sub
> gl
* c77f4b2  - (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) sub c2 (2 minutes ago) VonC
* b7d1c40  - sub c1 (2 minutes ago) VonC
* 1b8144b  - subsub at HEAD-1 (3 minutes ago) VonC

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent\sub
> git checkout @~1
Note: checking out '@~1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
HEAD is now at b7d1c40... sub c1
```

Now, we add `sub` (checked out at its `c1` commit, not at its `c2 master` HEAD) to the `parent` repo:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent
> git add .
> git st
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitmodules
        new file:   sub


vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent
> git commit -m "sub at c1"
[master (root-commit) 27374ec] sub at c1
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 sub
```

Let's make `sub` follows `master` as a submodule in the repo `parent`:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent
> git config -f .gitmodules submodule.sub.branch master
> git diff
diff --git a/.gitmodules b/.gitmodules
index 8688a8c..97974c1 100644
--- a/.gitmodules
+++ b/.gitmodules
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 [submodule "sub"]
        path = sub
        url = ../sub
+       branch = master

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent
> git add .
> git commit -m "sub follows master"
[master 2310a02] sub follows master
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\parent
> gl
* 2310a02  - (HEAD -> master) sub follows master (1 second ago) VonC
* 27374ec  - sub at c1 (2 minutes ago) VonC
```

---

### BUG:

If I clone the repo `parent`, and then ask to any of its submodule to checkout following their remote branch, `sub` *and `subsub`* will checkout their `master` branch (while only `sub` should checkout `master`, `subsub` should remain at `c1`)

First the clone:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm
> git clone --recursive parent p1
Cloning into 'p1'...
done.
Submodule 'sub' (D:/git/tests/subm/sub) registered for path 'sub'
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/subm/p1/sub'...
done.
Submodule path 'sub': checked out 'b7d1c403edaddf6a4c00bbbaa8e2dfa6ffbd112f'
Submodule 'subsub' (D:/git/tests/subm/subsub) registered for path 'sub/subsub'
Cloning into 'D:/git/tests/subm/p1/sub/subsub'...
done.
Submodule path 'sub/subsub': checked out 'f3087a9bc9b743625e0799f57c017c82c50e35d6'
```

So far, so good: `sub` and `subsub` are checked out at `c1`, *not* `c2` (that is: not their `master HEAD c2`)

But:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\p1
> git submodule update --recursive --remote
Submodule path 'sub': checked out 'c77f4b2590794e030ec68a8cea23ae566701d2de'
Submodule path 'sub/subsub': checked out '03d08cc81e3b9c0734b8f53fad03ea7b1f0373df'
```

Now, from the clone `p1`, both submodule and subsubmodule are at their `master HEAD c2`.

And that, even so `sub` (checked out at its `master` as expected) still has `subsub` at `c2`:

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\p1\sub
> git ls-tree @
100644 blob 25a0feba7e1c1795be3b8e7869aaa5dba29d33e8    .gitmodules
160000 commit f3087a9bc9b743625e0799f57c017c82c50e35d6  subsub
```

---

### Workaround:

Without modifying anything within `sub` and `subsub`, here is how to make sure `subsub` remains at its expected `c1` commit instead of following `master` (like `sub` is supposed to)

Call `git submodule update --recursive` from the submodule which has itself nested submodules (so no `--remote` here)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\p1\sub
> git submodule update --recursive
Submodule path 'subsub': checked out 'f3087a9bc9b743625e0799f57c017c82c50e35d6'
```

We now have:

- `sub` remaining at `master` (because of parent `.gitmodules` `branch` directive, and its initial `git submodule update --recursive --remote`)
- `subsub` is set back to its recorded sha1 (`c1`, not `master c2`)

---

## Conclusion

1. It does look like a bad design: `--recursive` applies the `--remote` to *all* nested submodules, defaulting to master when no `submodule.<path>.<branch>` is found.
2. You can script your way out of this in order to:

- `update --remote` what you want
- resetting any submodule which has no branch specified in the top parent repo `.gitmodules` file to their proper SHA1.

Simply create anywhere in your `%PATH%` the `git-subupd` script (a bash script, which will work even in a regular Windows `CMD` session, because it will be interpreted by the git bash)

`git-subupd`:

```
#!/bin/bash
git submodule update --recursive --remote
export top=$(pwd)
git submodule foreach --recursive 'b=$(git config -f ${top}/.gitmodules submodule.${path}.branch); case "${b}" in "") git checkout ${sha1};; esac'
```

The "combinations of git commands" is reduced to one git call:

```
cd /path/to/parent/repo
git subupd
```

That is it.
(Any script called `git-xxx` can be called by git with `git xxx`)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\tests\subm\p1
> git subupd
Submodule path 'sub/subsub': checked out '03d08cc81e3b9c0734b8f53fad03ea7b1f0373df'
Entering 'sub'
Entering 'sub/subsub'
Previous HEAD position was 03d08cc... subsub c2
HEAD is now at f3087a9... subsub c1
```

`sub` remains set to `master` (commit `c2`, unchanged), while `subsub` is reset to `c1` (instead of its `master c2`).

The [OP BartBog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274140/bartbog) declares [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879715/git-track-branch-in-submodule-but-commit-in-other-submodule-possibly-nested/37924157#comment63420072_37924157) using a slight variation of that script with:

```
export top=$(pwd)
git submodule foreach --recursive \
  'b=$(git config -f ${top}/.gitmodules submodule.${path}.branch); \
   case "${b}" in \
     "") git checkout ${sha1};; \
      *) git checkout ${b}; git pull origin ${b};; \
   esac'
```

> to avoid the call to `submodule update --remote` AND to make sure that my submodules are not in detached head state (conform [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854)).

Comment: I clarified in my question what I mean by "do wrong stuff" and provided a simple example where it goes wrong.

Comment: @BartBog OK. I have revised my answer, adding a full test, and a possible workaround (which does not involve any modification for the submodules)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug: the documentation mentions that this is how --remote is supposed to work .It is just a bad design choice I guess.

Comment: One more problem with this solution is that I essentially would have to do your two extra commands for all submodules (that got updated by the --remote command)

Comment: @BartBog No, it looks like a bug. The doc says: " Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch." It says nothing about nested submodules

Comment: @BartBog I did say it is a workaround: there is no easy solution here.

Comment: @BartBog I am working on a script to automate that process through *one* global command.

Comment: but you call it with --recursive, so it should also be applied to subsubmodules. And thee documentation says that --remote "defaults to master" if the branch is unset. This is the case here

Comment: I see. Such a script would be useful!

Comment: @BartBog Script done. Answer edited. All submodules are now reset to their proper SHA1 (if no branch was specified for them)

Comment: Hi VonC, I don't consider it completely accepted yet (but I did reward the bonus already since you earned it!). Three more comments. 1. The script is currently not working with me, saying "eval: [[: not found" 2. maybe it would be better to change it to a oneliner that avoids first checking out the wrong branch and then fixing it. Something like "git submodule foreach --recursive 'b=$(git config -f ${top}/.gitmodules submodule.${path}.branch); if [[ "${b}" == "" ]]; then git checkout ${sha1}; else git checkout ${b}; fi'". 3. This script takes quite long to run. But this is probably not fixable

Comment: @BartBog I mentioned "accepted" because I realized I have an old answer to your first question which is still not accepted ;) What is your OS on which you are running this script? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Linux. 3.13.0-88-generic GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: @BartBog OK, let me test that in Linux (16.04 though, mint)

Comment: @BartBog I have modified the script, removing the if, and replacing it with a more portable switch case esac syntax (http://stackoverflow.com/a/229585/6309. It seems to be working both on Windows and Linux. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Exactly what I was looking for! I will be using a slight variation: ```export top=$(pwd);
git submodule foreach --recursive 'b=$(git config -f ${top}/.gitmodules submodule.${path}.branch); case "${b}" in "") git checkout ${sha1};; *) git checkout ${b}; git pull origin ${b};; esac'``` to avoid the call to submodu update --remote AND to make sure that my submodules are not in detached head state (conform your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)

Comment: Great \o/ I am on my phone right now. I will edit the answer later this afternoon.

Comment: @BartBog I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: After a long while I stumbled onto this issue again. 
The current answer does not work that well (anymore?) with subsubmodules since $top/.gitmodules does not contain the branch info of the subsub (and subsubsub modules)

New solution:
`export top=$(pwd)
git submodule foreach 'b=$(git config -f ${top}/.gitmodules submodule.${path}.branch); case "${b}" in "") git checkout ${sha1}; git su ;; *) git checkout ${b}; git pull origin ${b}; git su;; esac' ` where `git-su` is the name of my script

Comment: @BartBog Thank you for this feedback. I have updated the answer accordingly, and included your comment for more visibility.