# How to configure parent repo to update from head of submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a parent repo A and submodule repo B, which is checked out at the latest commit on master. I've already ran a `git submodule update --init --recursive` in repo A, so my submodule is already inside it. I know I can throw a `--remote` flag onto that command to get it to update from the latest commit, but what I haven't been able to figure out is how to change the submodule commit # such that whenever someone else runs a `git submodule update --init --recursive`, it will update from the latest commit in the submodule as well. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> `git submodule update --init --recursive`, it will update from the latest commit in the submodule as well.

No, that command only checks out the submodule at is recorded **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)).

You need to add the `--remote` to force the branch update (git pull within th submodule)
But keep in mind any submodule would be updated, defaulting to their upstream master branch if no `submodule.<path>.<branch>` is found in the `.gitmodules`.
See "[Git: track branch in submodule but commit in other submodule (possibly nested)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37879715/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

1) cd into submodule
2) since the last submodule update had me on a commit that wasn't the latest, I just checked out the latest commit (`git checkout [commit_hash]`)
3) cd out of there and back into the parent repo
4) git add submodule --> commit --> push

Comment: You don't need that: if your submodule is set to track a branch (that is if it has a `submodule.<path>.<branch>` in its `.gitmodules`) the `--remote` is enough.