# Why does my git repo submodule fail to get updated?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo (parent project) that relies on a submodule.  I need to update the submodule to the latest commit but it is not working.

I created the submodule like this:
`git submodule add https://github.com/library.git` (not the real name)

I tried to update it with this:
`git submodule update --remote --merge`

It does not work. I still have the old code in the parent project. When I look at the code in the repo of the submodule the new code is there.

I updated the repo of the submodule, commit and push. That works. I update the submodule in the parent project, that does not work. I make a change to the parent project, commit and push. The submodule is still not updated.

I tried `git submodule --init` as suggested in one post. This is a terrible command.  First, it copies all the code in the submodule to the parent project which is a waste, potential source for errors now with the same code in two locations plus its the exact same wrong (old) code.

If I issue this command: `git submodule update --remote --merge`, I get no response.

Anyone know how I can update the parent project to point to the latest submodule?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found if I delete the submodule and then add it again I get the latest push.  Not ideal, but at least it works and I can move forward.

```
git submodule deinit -f path
git rm -f path
```

Im not sure exactly what those commands do, but I followed a recommendation and it worked.  Id still be interested in doing this a better way.

Answer (score 0):

`git submodule update --remote` should have updated the code of the submodule with the latest from, by default, `master`.

But if it des not work by default:

1. Make sure you are using the latest Git 2.28 (if not, upgrade and check if the issue persists)
2. Try and recreate the module, this time [specifying which branch you want to track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309) (`git submodule add -b master <URL to Git repo>`)
3. If nothing work, try the script at the [beginning of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37924157/6309), which will go into each module and pull.